# How can i make a div to slide in from right side to left?

Tags: jquery, css

How can i make a div to slide in from right side to left using css and jQuery? but I can't use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) from jQuery because I want to make the div can be scrolled down when it come out and if I use toggleClass() the scrollbar disappear. [This is the bug that I get from toggleClass()](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12951).

Here my div code:

```
<div id="menu-home" >
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="search rounded" id="input" placeholder="Search.." >
  </form>
  <span class="categories">Categories</span>
  <ul>
    <li id="menu1">Menu</li>
    <li id="menu2">Menu</li>
    <li id="menu3">Menu</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the button to trigger menu

```
<div class="btn-right button_search" style="">
  <img src="img/search_icon.png" />
</div>
```

And Here my css

```
#menu-home-search{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    padding-top:50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: fixed; 
    background: #34a6db;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: "`if I use toogleClass() the scroll will disappear`" What's your CSS? `.toggleClass` can't remove scrollbars on its own...

Comment: it is the scrollbar from div, I want to add a scrollbar on div, and it disappear when i using toggleClass from jQuery, it is not the page scrollbar but the div scrollbar

Comment: Since we don't have your code, we can't help. What does your try with toggleClass() look like?

Comment: @Bonatoc I use toggleClass() to add class from some css animation plugin, but I have a problem with the plugin itself, so I'm trying to use another css now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to Rusher's answer, animate should work. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4GLNy/)

CSS:

```
#movingImage
{
    margin-left:100%;

    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="movingImage"></div>
    <a href="#" id="clickMe">Make it Move!</a>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $('#movingImage').animate({'marginLeft':0}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery Animate?
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Some code:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "div" ).animate({
    marginLeft: "-=50"
  }, 5000});
});
```